# What is the set of points with equal distances to three straight lines on different surfaces

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I guess it's a straight line, which is the axis of a hyperboloid of one sheet, and the three straight lines on different surfaces given are a family of generatrix of this hyperboloid of one sheet

Comment: You mean normals from the generators of 1 sheeted hyperboloid  to the axis are all equal? But that happens to all curved meridian generators on parallels of a surface of revolution.

Comment: What I mean is to find a set of points with equal distances between three straight lines on different surfaces, rather than straight lines. I just speculate that these points form a straight line, and I hope I explain it clearly

Comment: I understand the question as:Given 3 skew straight lines find a surface S containing  three straight lines  and also find another line A associated  with S... such that from any point on A to any of the three lines the three (minimum  perpendicular )  distances are equal.

Comment: Yes, there is one point that these three lines are non-coplanar.

Comment: Furthermore, I speculate that the surface S is a hyperboloid of one sheet, and the line A is its principal axis.